# I have configured every thing but django says page not found

Tags: django

can any one help me with this problem?

this is my blog/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path("/testTemplate", template_testing, name="testtemplate"),
]
```

and this is my website/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls'))
] +  static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and this is blog/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
# Create your views here.

def template_testing(request):
    return render(request, "blog/index.html", {})
```

every things looks OK but when I want to go to this url: **127.0.0.1:8000/testTemplate** I get a page not found error. What is going wrong here?

please help me!

Comment: try `127.0.0.1:8000/testTemplate/`

Comment: Does blog/index.html actually exist?

Comment: Have you started a server with manage.py runserver at this port?

Comment: One more: have you registered your app `blog` in settings.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, make sure that your test server is running by going to the directory containing manage.py. Then make sure you have typed:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Once you've done this, note that the trouble with your script is that the method "template_testing" is not referencing the correct render file. Change the following lines:

```
def template_testing(request):
    return render(request, "blog/index.html", {})
```

To:

```
def template_testing(request):
    return render(request, "testTemplate", {})
```

Answer (score 0):

the template names you mentioned in blog/urls.py and in blog/views.py are different

both must contain same template name.